# Generics class cast in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

Hi I have very similar classes (Cars, Clients, Reservations). In those classes i have the same functions like ( add, delete, getItem, getAll and sort).

```
public class Clients {  
    List<Client> persons = new ArrayList<Client>(); 

    public void add (Client k) {
        persons.add(k);
    }

    public void delete (Client k) {
        persons.remove(k);
    }

    public Client getKlienet(int id) {
       for ( Client k: persons) {
           if ( k.getId() == id)
               return k;
       }            

       return null;
    }

    public List<Client> getAllClients() {
        List<Client> temp = new ArrayList<Client>();                
        temp.addAll(persons);   

        return temp;
    }

    public List<Client> sortujKontakty() {
        Collections.sort(persons);          

        return persons;
    }
```

I'd like to do with these classes one generic class. But i have a lot of problems..
First with function `getId()` (this function simply returns value of Id), and with `sort()` method. `Compareto()` methods are different for other classes.

So, i done interface:

```
public interface ManagerInterface <T> { 
    public void    add (T t );
    public void    delete ( T t);
    public T       getRecord(int id);
    public List<T> getAll();
    public List<T> sort();  
}
```

And class:

```
public class RecordManager<T> implements RecordManagerInterface <T> {
    private T id;

    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> record = new ArrayList<T>();

    @Override
    public void add(T t) {
        record.add(t);  
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T t) {
        record.remove(t);
    }

    @Override
    public T getRecord(int id) {
        for ( T k: record) {
            if ( ((Client) k).getId() == id)
                return k;
            else if ( ((Person) k).getId() == id)
                return k;
            else if ( ((Reservation) k).getId() == id)
                return k;               
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> getAll() {
        List<T> temp = new ArrayList<T>();              

        temp.addAll( record);   

        return temp;        
    }

    @Override
    public  List<T> sort() {
        Collections.sort(record);           

        return record;      

    }
```

Please for any help.

Comment: Read up on [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure). Also, you could implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Answer (score 1):

if you have similar classes, try to create common interface for them,

ie

```
interface  HasId { 
int getId();
}
```

then all what you need is make your classes to implement it, and change your `RecordManager` to be

```
public class RecordManager<T extends HasId> implements RecordManagerInterface <T> {
...
}
```

that means your T has to implement your interface,
so your get `getRecord` method will be much simpler

```
 public T getRecord(int id) {
        for ( T k: record) {
           if (k.getId() == id)
               return k;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

---

**EDIT**
Lets say your common interface will be

```
 interface CommonInterface<T> extends Comparable<T> {
 public int getId(); 
}
```

then definition of your class will be, ie

```
Person implements CommonInterface<Person> {
...
}
```

your `RecordManager`

```
 class RecordManager<T extends CommonInterface<T>> implements
            RecordManagerInterface<T>{
}
```

and that should fix all your problems with sort

Comment: Thanks for advice. But i have one problem still unresolved. Im my sort() function i have to implement Comparable and what then? compareTo() method looks different in different classes..But in class Client, Person and Reservation sort() looks the same (just 2 lines of code)

Comment: @volly your common interface can extend comparable

Comment: But i get error:  Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<T>). The inferred type T is not a valid substitute for the 
 bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>

Comment: @volly i edited answer, have a look now, it should works

Comment: Ok, but in RecordManager i must implement compareTo() method.. But in class Client,Cars, Reservations i have implemented compareTo() methods. So did I something wrong ?

Comment: @volly you dont have to, you dont need compare your `RecordManager` With anything else, so it doesn't need to implement `Comparable`, you comparing `Client`s `Car`s etc so they need to implement it, and they do as their common interface extends it. now when you call `Collection.sort(record);` method sort calls `compareTo` implemented in class which you are sorting

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called "coding to the interface". Then when you instantiate the objects, make your reference to the interface and the object to the specific class you want to instantiate.

Ex:

```
Interface example = new Class();
```

Then use example.getMethod(), example.setMethod(). This will actually call the Class.getMethod() if it has one, as per inheritance.